# SBS2008 (Outlook/Exchange) How to change permission on public folder calendar

Tags: exchange, outlook, windows-sbs-2008

A user in my office created a shared calendar on our public folder in outlook, they have set everyone up as an author but I need to add another user as author and they are out of the office for four weeks. For security reasons, I cannot get the owners password so I am wondering if anyone knows a workaround to change these permissions from the exchange server.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open EMC, navigate to "TOOLS" sub-tree, connect to the server, if not connected already, find the appropriate calendar/folder and adjust permissions as necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tried that, but the tool does not allow you to adjust permissions.

Comment: Right click on the folder, properties, permissions tab. Or right-click, Manage Settings and assign permissions through there. Have you validated that you have the appropriate rights when performing those tasks?

Comment: HI Vick, I don't seem to have the correct access rights, even though I am logged into the server with an acc which is part of the admin/local admin/exchange admin/domain admin

Comment: Google for "Exchange Management rights" or "Public Folders full management rights"